# Estou com um problema para validar um formulado de contato

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Codigo html:

```
    <section class="contato">   
    <div class="parallax-targetaf section-0" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/4.jpeg">
    <div class="container cf">
    <div class="containerrr">  
  <form id="contact" action="mail_send.php" method="post">
    <h3>Precisa de Ajuda?</h3>
    <h4>Entraremos em contato em 24 horas úteis.</h4>
    <fieldset>
    <input required placeholder="Digite seu nome" type="text" name="nome" >
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input required placeholder="Digite seu email" type="email" name="email">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input required placeholder="Deixe o seu numero (Opicional)" type="text"  name="telefone">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea required placeholder="Digite sua mensagem ...." name="mensagem"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="BTEnvia" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Enviando">Enviar</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


                </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

codigo php :

```
<?php

function pegaValor($valor) {
    return isset($_POST[$valor]) ? $_POST[$valor] : '';
}

function validaEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

function enviaEmail ($nome, $de, $telefone, $msg , $para, $email_servidor) {
    $headers = "From: $email_servidor\r\n" .
               "Reply-To: $de\r\n" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  mail($para, $assunto, nl2br($mensagem), $headers);
}

$email_servidor = "supporttt@secbost.com";
$para = "lostspirit15@gmail.com";
$nome = pegaValor("nome");
$de = pegaValor("email");
$telefone = pegaValor("telefone");
$msg = pegaValor("mensagem");


if (validaEmail($de) && $mensagem) {
enviaEmail($nome, $de, $telefone, $msg , $para, $email_servidor);
$pagina = "mail_ok.php";
} else {
$pagina = "mail_error.php";
}

header("location:$pagina");
?>
```

testei no meu local host e só vai para pagina mail_error.php não sei por qual motivo alguém poderia me ajuda onde eu estou errando?

E se tiver como alguém adicionar um exemplo de qnd clicar em "ENVIAR", ao invez de abrir uma pagina aparecer um "alert" em js ou ajax. ( Email enviado com sucesso ou de error) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é porque você está capturando o valor da variável `$mensagem`, porém ela não existe.

Substitua

```
if (validaEmail($de) && $mensagem) {
```

para

```
if (validaEmail($de) && $msg) {
```

e substitua

```
mail($para, $assunto, nl2br($mensagem), $headers);
```

para

```
mail($para, $assunto, nl2br($msg), $headers);
```

---

Enviando e-mail via `javascript`

**Javascript:**

```
<section class="contato">
  <div class="parallax-targetaf section-0" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/4.jpeg">
    <div class="container cf">
      <div class="containerrr">
        <form id="contact">
          <h3>Precisa de Ajuda?</h3>
          <h4>Entraremos em contato em 24 horas úteis.</h4>
          <fieldset>
            <input required placeholder="Digite seu nome" type="text" name="nome">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input required placeholder="Digite seu email" type="email" name="email">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input required placeholder="Deixe o seu numero (Opicional)" type="text" name="telefone">
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <textarea required placeholder="Digite sua mensagem ...." name="mensagem"></textarea>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <button name="BTEnvia" type="button" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Enviando">Enviar</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script>
    /* Instancia o objeto para as requisições */
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    /* Captura o botão de envio do form */
    const btnSubmit = document.querySelector("#contact-submit");

    /* Captura o form de contato */
    const formContact = document.querySelector("#contact");

    /* Adiciona o evento para capturar o resultado da requisição */
    req.addEventListener("loadend", function(result){

      /* Converte a resposta para JSON */
      var response = JSON.parse(result.target.response);

      /* Verifica o resultado e exibe o alerta */
      if (response.success) {
        alert("Mensagem de Sucesso");
      } else {
        alert("Mensagem de Falha");
      }
    })

    /* Adiciona evento para envio dos dados */
    btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var form = new FormData(formContact);

      /* Abre a conexão do tipo POST e assíncrona */
      req.open("POST", "envia-email.php", true);

      /* Envia os dados */
      req.send(form);
    })
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

function pegaValor($valor) {
    return isset($_POST[$valor]) ? $_POST[$valor] : '';
}

function validaEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

function enviaEmail ($nome, $de, $telefone, $msg , $para, $email_servidor) {
    $headers = "From: $email_servidor\r\n" .
               "Reply-To: $de\r\n" .
               "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  mail($para, "Assunto", nl2br($msg), $headers);
}

$email_servidor = "supporttt@secbost.com";
$para = "lostspirit15@gmail.com";
$nome = pegaValor("nome");
$de = pegaValor("email");
$telefone = pegaValor("telefone");
$msg = pegaValor("mensagem");


if (validaEmail($de) && $msg) {
    enviaEmail($nome, $de, $telefone, $msg , $para, $email_servidor);
    $result = true;
} else {
    $result = false;
}

echo json_encode(["success" => $result]);
```

Comment: Opa valdeir me desculpe pela demora bro acabei dormindo, então se eu botar o email via javascript não vai precisar dessa parte de php bro? E no caso eu só precisaria chamar no form o arquivo js ou precisaria chamar depois do head tb?

Comment: @Felipe não entendi. Enviando via `js`, o — esse código — `php` irá conseguir trabalhar com os dados. A única coisa que vai mudar em seu código `php` (além dos erros supracitados), será o retorno, que será em JSON.

Comment: Ah ok, tipo eu falei eu precisaria no action do form chamar esse arquivo . js não é isso? Além disso eu precisaria chamar esse arquivo na parte do head tb?

Comment: No caso o form teria q ser assim :   <form id="contact" action="enviojs.js" method="post"> e eu teria q criar um arquivo : envia-email.php com esse codigo php?

Comment: Entendi. Basta você adicionar o js dentro da tag `<script></script>` e alterar o `type` do botão submit para `type="button"`. Qualquer coisa posso postar o código html já com o código js.

Comment: opa mano se tiver como seria mt ajuda, mt obrigado. Então o js vai trabalhar sozinho ou em conjunto com php? Pq eu vi essa :  req.open("POST", "envia-email.php", true);

Comment: Editado. O `js` não irá trabalhar em conjunto com o `php`. Esse código que você mencionou, serve para abrir uma conexão para depois enviar os dados. É basicamente a mesma coisa que o `action="envia-email.php"`, a diferença é que o usuário não sairá da página.

Comment: opa mano tranquilo o method vc deixou chamando o action="mail_send.php" isso ta certo?

Comment: Acabei esquecendo, mas ele será ignorado pelo código. Modifiquei o código.

Comment: e onde q eu botaria o email do servidor essas coisas ? E eu adicionei o codigo e cliquei em enviar e não aconteceu nada .

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum alert .

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71275/discussion-between-valdeir-psr-and-felipe).

Comment: Blz @Valdeir obg.